# XSLT enumeration mapping

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

Using xsl to transformer one xml to another xml schema.

how can i map enumeration of one xml with another.

example:
xsd 1:

```
<xsd:element  name="Hindi">
<xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="Chay" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="Roti" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

xsd 2:

```
<xsd:element  name="Hindi">
<xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="Tea" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="Bread" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

How can i map `chay` with `Tea` using xsl.

Input xml:

```
<Hindi>Chay</Hindi>
```

output xml:

```
<Hindi>Tea</Hindi>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking how to write the XSLT that will perform the two transformations (element name and string content)? -- P.S. Please indicate if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes you are right.. element Hindi --> English and string content mapping Chay --> Tea and Roti --> Bread

Comment: @michael.hor257k I updated my question element name is not bothering. I just want to map enumeration of bot xsd. Or we can say if Chay is selected in first xsd i need to replace with Tea same for Roti

Comment: I am afraid this doesn't answer my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by using `xsl:when`

```
<English>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Hindi = 'Chay'">Tea</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="Hindi = 'Roti'">Bread</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
<English>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are only using two languages or my code will not work. I did just code it quickly, so it might not be the fanciest code. Keep in mind, that the entries have to have the same order. So if you want to translate a word on position x in the enumeration, x has to be the position of the word in the other enumeration too.

Dictionary variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="dict">
    <element name="Hindi">
        <simpleType>
            <restriction base="xsd:string">
                <enumeration value="Inp1" />
                <enumeration value="Inp2" />
            </restriction>
        </simpleType>
    </element>
    <element name="English">
        <simpleType>
            <restriction base="xsd:string">
                <enumeration value="Bread1" />
                <enumeration value="Bread2" />
            </restriction>
        </simpleType>
    </element>
</xsl:variable>
```

Match template:

```
<!-- This will match on every node with a specified element/@name in the dictionary -->
<xsl:template match="*[name() = $dict/element/@name]">
    <xsl:variable name="fromLanguage" select="name()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="wordToTranslate" select="."/>
    <!-- My translation requires the same order of enumerations in order to do it correctly -->
    <!-- I am counting the preceding siblings, so we can take the xth element of the other dictionary -->
    <xsl:variable name="precSiblings" select="$dict/element[@name = $fromLanguage]//enumeration[@value = $wordToTranslate][1]/count(preceding-sibling::*)"/>
    <!-- Renaming the language node -->
    <xsl:element name="{$dict/element[@name != $fromLanguage]/@name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$dict/element[@name != $fromLanguage]//enumeration[$precSiblings + 1]/@value"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I updated my question element name is not bothering. I just want to map enumeration. Or we can say if Chay is selected in first xsd i need to replace with Tea same for Roti

Comment: So, is this working for you? If you want to keep the same element name, you can replace the <xsl:element name="{$dict/element[@name != $fromLanguage]/@name}"> with <xsl:copy>. This will copy your current input element which is considered in the match template.